# CSS : scrollable child <div>'s with fixed parent

Tags: css, scrollbar

I need scroll only child div's with fixed parent div. And also I don't want to set parent or child div's height. I have tried by setting overflow scroll for child div's but it is not working. Any way to do this?

```css
.parent {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  background: green;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child1 {
  min-height: 20%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.child2 {
  min-height: 20%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h1>Child 1</h1>
  <div class="child1">
    <ul>
      <li>Colors HOME</li>
      <li>Color Names</li>
      <li>Color Values</li>
      <li>Color Groups</li>
      <li>Color Shades</li>
      <li>Color Picker</li>
      <li>Color Mixer</li>
      <li>Color Converter</li>
      <li>Color RGB</li>
      <li>Color HEX</li>
      <li>Color HSL</li>
      <li>Color HWB</li>
      <li>Color CMYK</li>
      <li>Color NCol</li>
      <li>Colors HOME</li>
      <li>Color Names</li>
      <li>Color Values</li>
      <li>Color Groups</li>
      <li>Color Shades</li>
      <li>Color Picker</li>
      <li>Color Mixer</li>
      <li>Color Converter</li>
      <li>Color RGB</li>
      <li>Color HEX</li>
      <li>Color HSL</li>
      <li>Color HWB</li>
      <li>Color CMYK</li>
      <li>Color NCol</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h1>child2</h1>
  <div class="child2">
    <ul>
      <li>Colors USA</li>
      <li>Colors UK</li>
      <li>Colors Australia</li>
      <li>Colors RAL</li>
      <li>Colors NBS</li>
      <li>Colors NCS</li>
      <li>Colors Crayola</li>
      <li>Colors Resene</li>
      <li>Colors XKCD</li>
      <li>Colors Brands</li>
      <li>Colors Trends</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle demo here: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/NaghaveerGowda/083hhp7p/1/)

Comment: updated your fiddle kindly check https://jsfiddle.net/083hhp7p/4/  is this what you wanted?

Comment: hmmm read 2nd part of your question now... I dont think you can have scroll bar without setting the height